# Apex code to add Tab in Salesforce Main page

Tags: community

I have two Custom object(Project,Skill). Is there a way to add both the custom object in Salesforce tab using Apex coding. Currently I am adding using customize my tab option and selecting my object. I need this code to add it to Managed package.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your tabs to appear without the user having to add them your best approach is to [create an Application](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_tabsetcreate.htm&language=en_US) (under **Setup > Create > Applications**) and then add the tabs to that. Then include that [Application](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_tabsets.htm&language=en_US) in your Managed Package.

[image]

[image]

Once installed the administrator of the org can allow access to your Application and Tabs via Profiles and/or Permissions Sets, it will then appear in the drop down in the top right of the users screen, once they select it your tabs will be shown. Other than that there is no way to automatically customise your tabs onto an existing application on install.

Comment: I want to add my application tab to main page, i.e. in Sales app, i don't want select my application from application list

Comment: You can setup a user to have a default app so that your custom app will be what they see as soon as they log in without having to select it from the Application menu.